# Cant calibrate touchscreen on kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, touch, kivy, calibration

For my pi touchscreen project I am working with an -you guessed it- pi and an egalax touchdriver. The thing receives input and the touchscreen actually works, after some minor tweaking like inverting y_axis and stuff. However, at this moment I'm stuck trying to touch a certain button on the edge of the screen which I can't reach. I actually use a pen with the cursor enabled to make sure I know where the screen registers my input.

So after searching a bit in the kivy documents I came across [this postproc.calibration](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.postproc.calibration.html) module which should do the trick.

But it doesn't. I tried putting the following 2 code snippets in the `.kivy/config.ini` file:

```
[input]
egalax = hidinput,/dev/input/event0,rotation=90,invert_y=1

[postproc:calibration]
egalax = xratio=1.2,yratio=1.2
```

The `[input]` bit works, no problems there. the `[postproc:calibration]` bit is what doesn't work. I've tried putting the line above the `[postproc]` module, beneath it, even beneath the `[modules]` module. Also I've tried putting the `egalax = xratio=1.2,yratio=1.2` line IN the `[postproc]` module. Didn't seem to work. I've also tried to increase the floats to 2.0, but no changes.

So how would I 'expand' my area of touch input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem I found a solution from this source: [Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kivy-users/CZHC6DMEC6c/zcE2dlj8gNAJ). Just for clarification: it involves changing a file in the kivy install directories.

In `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/hdinput.py` insert the last line:

```
class HIDInputMotionEventProvider(MotionEventProvider):
    options = ('min_position_x', 'max_position_x',
               'min_position_y', 'max_position_y',
               'min_pressure', 'max_pressure',
               'invert_x', 'invert_y', 'rotation',
            -> 'min_abs_x', 'max_abs_x', 'min_abs_y', 'max_abs_y') # <- this one
```

Then in your .kivy/config.ini file you add this:

```
[input]
eGalax = hidinput,/dev/input/event1,rotation=90,min_abs_x=60,min_abs_y=90,max_abs_x=1985,max_abs_y=1970
```

With that atleast my touchscreen (an eGalax thing) is calibrated.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer re Kivy & Waveshare 10.1 inch touchscreen.
sudo nano .kivy/config.ini. I required the "param=rotation=90"

add

```
[input]
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput,param=rotation=90
```